# Could Proto-Germanic *tīhaną be a "ē-grade" of *tungǭ zero-grade?

Tags: proto-germanic

Could Proto-Germanic *tīhaną be an ē-grade of *tungǭ zero-grade?
Gothic has -h- / -ng-:

- huhrus – huggrjan
- juhiza – juggs
- ga-teihan – tuggo ?

Answer (score 5):

It is of course right that Gothic has Verner's Law variants -*χ*- / -*ng*-  (spelled <h>  /<gg>, respectively), as seen in your first two examples.

It is also right that *tuggo* has a zero grade root. However, *gateihan* cannot be an *ē*-grade, as PIE **-ē-* will develop to PGmc. **-ē₁-*, which will result in Gothic -*ē*- as in Gothic *nemun* '(they) took' (from *niman* 'to take). The verb *gateihan* rather has the regular *e*-grade root (full grade), which in the present/infinitive of a strong verb of class I is regularly represented by -*ī*- (spelled <ei>), < PGmc. **-ī-* < **-ei-*.

So I guess that your real question is whether PGmc. **tīχan*- 'to announce' could be the *e*-grade and PGmc. **tungō*- 'tongue' the zero grade of one and the same root. The answer to this is no, at least according to standard textbook knowledge. The 'tongue' word is  a cognate of Latin *lingua* < Old Latin *dingua* < PIE *dn̥ǵʰweh₂- (Casaretto 2004: 230). This is considered to be a pure nominal stem, without a verbal root. PGmc. **tīχan*- is derived from the verbal root PIE **deyḱ*- 'to show' (Lehmann 1986: 150) and compared to Latin *dīcō* 'I speak' etc. These two reconstructions are not reconcilable.

**References**

Casaretto, Antje (2004). *Nominale Wortbildung der gotischen Sprache. Die Derivation der Substantive*. Heidelberg: Winter.

Lehmann, Winfred P. (1986). *A Gothic Etymological Dictionary*. Leiden: Brill.

Comment: Also, would a long ē not be shortened before /ng/ in Germanic? I’m going purely off memory here and I can’t think of any actual sound change as such, but I can’t recall _any_ Germanic words with a long vowel before a nasal cluster…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet there's the notorious "einklich" pronounciation spelling for *eigentlich*, aeggshuly

Comment: @vectory Proto-Germanic, I meant. There are plenty such words in modern Germanic languages (English _round_, German _Gemeinde_, Icelandic _frændi_, etc.), but those are all the result of later developments.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Understand I the relevance of your premise? If you are right then vowel quantity was not contrastive. Anyhow, cp. \*fanhaną (/ˈɸɑ̃ː.xɑ.nɑ̃/), WGem \*fą̄han. No PIE derivation. Incidently, cp. *feint* (Latin *fictus* "deceive", \*finctus, *fingo*, "Cognates include Ancient Greek τεῖχος (teîkhos), Sanskrit देग्धि (degdhi) and English *dough*") also cp. *täuschen* "deceive", *tauschen* "change", Engl. *mix, mix-up, make (dough)*, *verfänglich, befangen, cepto* "catch", *Fangnetz* (*net, knot, nass*?), *Knete* "play-doe; pay". I haven't got the *hang* of the concept but it's Fun!

Comment: @vectory I don’t think vowel length was contrastive before nasal clusters in PGmc., no. So even if PIE _*dn̥ɡ̑ʰú-_ did have a long _e_-grade _*dēng̑ʰ(u?)-_, it would not have ended up with an _ē_ in Gothic if _*V̄NC_ clusters were reduced to _*VNC_ as I think they were: the relevant PGmc. form would be _*teng-_, which would remain in Gothic. Of course, the Verner variant with _*-χ-_ could never arise in this root to begin with, since it never had a _*k_; but if the root had been _*denk-_ instead, _ē_-grade _*dēnk-_ would probably have yielded Gothic _*teih[an]_.

Comment: Ah! Remembering who gave their name to what law helps too. Shortening of vowels before _*NC_ clusters (or rather, _*RC_ clusters in general) is _Osthoff’s Law_, and it is indeed said to have applied to Germanic. This, combined with the raising of _*e_ to _*i_ before _*NC_ clusters which also occurred in PGmc., confirms my initial point: the vowel <ei> in _gateihan_ does not preclude it from being an _ē_-grade form, but the <h> does mean that it cannot be from the same root that yielded _tuggo_, which we know from comparative evidence had _*g̑ʰ_, not _*k_.

Comment: I looked into Kloekhorst's Hittite Dictionary, found no cognate, only *lāla* "tongue,..." (where he missed the chance to call it a lull-word). This means to me \*dn̥ɡ̑ʰú-  is unlikely PIE original, or Anatolian isn't--which is both difficult to claim. This goes towards supposing n was epenthetic in zero grade only, notwithstanding the coda. No palatal voiceless labio velar exists, so I blame \*-w-eh2 for causing irregularities there.